# PowerShell - Parse through comma delimited text file and insert values into SQL table

Tags: sql, powershell, parsing

I have a text file that contains file names, file sizes, and created dates for before (.txt) and after (.txt.Z) compression. The data is separated by commas and looks like this:

**Note:** The File names below are not the actual file names. I will be receiving this type of file weekly, so each week the files would be different names.

```
File1.txt,1449124525,Jul 09 01:13
File2.txt,2601249364,Jul 09 01:30
File3.txt,18105630,Jul 09 01:01
File4.txt,732235442,Jul 09 01:17
File1.txt.Z,130652147,Jul 09 01:13
File2.txt.Z,217984273,Jul 09 01:30
File3.txt.Z,2320129,Jul 09 01:01
File4.txt.Z,61196011,Jul 09 01:17
```

etc...

Currently, the code that I have inserts the first row into SQL 44 times (there are 22 total file names, so 44 total with before and after compression).

```
$file = Get-Content "MY_FILE.txt"

$line = $null

foreach ($line in $file)
{
    #Split fields into values
    $line = $file -split (",")
    $FileName = $line[0]
    $FileSize = $line[1]
    $FileDate = $line[2]

    #Format Date Field
    $DateString = $FileDate
    $DateFormat = "MMM dd HH:mm"
    $Culture = $(New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo -ArgumentList "en-US")
    $DateString = $DateString -replace "\s+"," "
    $NewDate = [Datetime]::ParseExact($DateString, $DateFormat, $Culture)
    $FileDate = Get-Date $NewDate -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

    #SQL Connection Info
    $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
    $Connection.ConnectionString = "server='MY_SERVER';database='MY_DATABASE';trusted_connection=true;"
    $Connection.Open()
    $Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
    $Command.Connection = $Connection

    #Insert into SQL
    $sql = "INSERT INTO [MY_DATABASE].[dbo].[MY_TABLE] ([FileName],[FileSize],[FileDate]) VALUES ('" + $FileName + "'," + $FileSize + ",'" + $FileDate + "')"

    $Command.CommandText = $sql 
    $Command.ExecuteReader()
}

$Connection.Close()
```

Another tricky thing that I would love to be able to do would be to load each file, and its corresponding size and date, to the same row for before and after compression. I cannot seem to grasp how I would be able to get that. The above part is more important, though. Anyway, I would want it to look like this in SQL:

```
| InFileName | InFileSize | InFileDate   | OutFileName | OutFileSize | OutFileDate  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| File1.txt  | 1449124525 | Jul 09 01:13 | File1.txt.Z | 130652147   | Jul 09 01:13 |
| File2.txt  | 2601249364 | Jul 09 01:30 | File2.txt.Z | 217984273   | Jul 09 01:30 |
| File3.txt  | 18105630   | Jul 09 01:01 | File3.txt.Z | 2320129     | Jul 09 01:01 |
| File4.txt  | 732235442  | Jul 09 01:17 | File4.txt.Z | 61196011    | Jul 09 01:17 |
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you process the data first, before importing into SQL server. If you're using comma-separated-values, use Import-CSV.

As an addition to that, you can specify column names when importing, so I've added empty columns for the compressed files.

Then loop over the rows, and merge in the compressed files - note that their names come from the "InFileName" column, and get moved to the "OutFileName" column. It's not particularly efficient; for every file without a `.z` ending, it loops through all the rows to find the corresponding `.z` file.

```
$fileHeaders = 'InFileName','InFileSize','InFileDate','OutFileName','OutFileSize','OutFileDate'
$inData = Import-Csv D:\f.txt -Header $fileHeaders

$outData = foreach ($row in $inData) {
    if ($row.InFileName -notmatch '\.z$') {
        $outFile = $inData | Where {$_.InFileName -match "$($row.InFileName).."}
        $row.OutFileName = $outFile.InFileName
        $row.OutFileSize = $outFile.InFileSize
        $row.OutFileDate = $outFile.InFileDate
        $row
    }
}
```

e.g. after that:

```
$outData | ft -AutoSize

InFileName InFileSize InFileDate   OutFileName OutFileSize OutFileDate 
---------- ---------- ----------   ----------- ----------- ----------- 
File1.txt  1449124525 Jul 09 01:13 File1.txt.Z 130652147   Jul 09 01:13
File2.txt  2601249364 Jul 09 01:30 File2.txt.Z 217984273   Jul 09 01:30
File3.txt  18105630   Jul 09 01:01 File3.txt.Z 2320129     Jul 09 01:01
File4.txt  732235442  Jul 09 01:17 File4.txt.Z 61196011    Jul 09 01:17
```

Then loop over $outData and you'll have to change your SQL inserts and so on to handle the 6 fields. You'll still need all the date parsing / field processing code as well, which I left out completely.

Comment: First off, thank you for the amazing response. This has been giving me a headache for a month. I threw in my SQL insert statement after the `IF` statement right before the `FOREACH` loop ends. It ended up inserting 44 rows, though. The first 22 rows were exactly what I needed, but the last 22 it repeated each InFileName one more time with its corresponding FileSize and FileDate, and the last OutFileName file was repeated for every row.

Comment: Since half the lines of input have to be taken out and thrown away, you have to take care of where you do the SQL inserts. Either do it *inside* the `if`, at the end, where `$row` is the uncompressed files + filled in extra data, or write a `foreach ($row in $outData) {}` loop completely after the first loop, it might be clearer there.

Comment: Awesome got it work by adding it inside the `IF` at the end. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like in the first line of your foreach loop you are calling split on the entire $file array rather than on the $line you are working with.  It should work if you swap `$line = $file -split (",")` for `$line = $line -split (",")`.  Although you may want to use a different name for either the parameter or the variable you are assigning it to.

Comment: Thanks this worked. Only thing is that it didn't seem to load them in the same order as the file had them. Do you happen to know of a fix for that?